# Why does after_commit filter calls the function twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filter

I just realized when I use after_commit filter, it seems to be executing the function twice (reasons unknown to me)

Controller:

```
def new
    @upload_files = UploadFiles.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @upload_files }
    end
  end

  # GET /uploads/1/edit
  def edit
    @uploadFiles = Upload.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /uploads
  # POST /uploads.json
  def create
    @upload_files = UploadFiles.create(params[:upload_files])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @upload_files.save
        redirect_to @upload_files
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @upload_files.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

template:

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= form_for :upload_files, :url => upload_files_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<h4>Upload Inventory</h4>
<div><%= f.file_field :inventory %></div>
<h4>Upload Material List</h4>
<div><%= f.file_field :material_list %></div>
&nbsp;
<div align="center">
    <%= f.submit "Upload" %>
</div>
<% end %>

class UploadFiles < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :process_files

def process_files
    @init_process=Time.now
    out_file = File.new("times.txt", "w")
    out_file.puts("Init Time")
    out_file.puts(Time.now)
    logger.info "Processing the request..."
    logger.info Time.now
    logger.info "Processing Files..."
    logger.info Time.now
.
.
.
end
end
```

Log:

```
Started POST "/upload_files" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-17 10:20:06 -0430
Processing by UploadFilesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"NpCyDUNq8uPwJMj2DofP4rHEZWYkfsIu68Wg+XqebNk=", "upload_files"=>{"inventory"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x4df7648 @original_filename="INV Onhand -753233-2013090621595800.xlsx", @content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload_files[inventory]\"; filename=\"INV Onhand -753233-2013090621595800.xlsx\"\r\nContent-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:C:/Users/V80042~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20131017-7356-1i1m655>>, "material_list"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x4df7408 @original_filename="Formato SCL Movistar1.xlsx", @content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload_files[material_list]\"; filename=\"Formato SCL Movistar1.xlsx\"\r\nContent-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:C:/Users/V80042~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20131017-7356-fqdioq>>}, "commit"=>"Upload"}
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 5 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `inventory_content_type`
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `material_list_content_type`
  [1m[35mSQL (2.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "upload_files" ("created_at", "inventory_content_type", "inventory_file_name", "inventory_file_size", "inventory_updated_at", "material_list_content_type", "material_list_file_name", "material_list_file_size", "material_list_updated_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Thu, 17 Oct 2013 14:50:06 UTC +00:00], ["inventory_content_type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"], ["inventory_file_name", "INV_Onhand_-753233-2013090621595800.xlsx"], ["inventory_file_size", 6776337], ["inventory_updated_at", Thu, 17 Oct 2013 14:50:06 UTC +00:00], ["material_list_content_type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"], ["material_list_file_name", "Formato_SCL_Movistar1.xlsx"], ["material_list_file_size", 42608], ["material_list_updated_at", Thu, 17 Oct 2013 14:50:06 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Thu, 17 Oct 2013 14:50:06 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[36m (4.0ms)[0m  [1mcommit transaction[0m
Processing the request...
2013-10-17 10:20:07 -0430
Processing Files...
2013-10-17 10:20:07 -0430
Inventory Opened...
2013-10-17 10:21:47 -0430
Material List Opened...
2013-10-17 10:21:48 -0430
Default Sheets were set...
Output file created...
2013-10-17 10:21:48 -0430
Code and Name read...
2013-10-17 10:21:48 -0430
Beginning Inventory reading...
2013-10-17 10:21:48 -0430
Inventory completely read...
2013-10-17 10:57:54 -0430
Total Time reading and Parsing Inventory...
2013-10-17 10:57:54 -0430
Output file created...
2013-10-17 10:58:00 -0430
Process Finished...
2013-10-17 10:58:00 -0430
  [1m[35m (1095.0ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36m (19.0ms)[0m  [1mcommit transaction[0m
Processing the request...
2013-10-17 10:58:03 -0430
Processing Files...
2013-10-17 10:58:03 -0430
failed to allocate memory
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/upload_files/157
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 2293951ms (ActiveRecord: 1124.0ms)
```

The file is obviously too large and it throws failed to allocate memory but if it didn't i'm pretty sure it would execute it again...

Why does it execute it again?

I tried using after_create and after_save but it throws an exception saying the .xlsx files aren't present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood what you meant correctly, you're doing multiple saves in your controller's `create` action, as both `UploadFiles.create` and `@upload_files.save` trigger a database operation.

Perhaps you meant `UploadFiles.new`?

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't find the reason for this. I'm new to ruby and rails. My bad